# HTACCESS: Change domain root to sub-directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, root

I'm trying to use a sub-directory as the root folder for one of my domains. Using .htaccess, I use mod_rewrite's to get the job done. Here's the code I already have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /domain/index.php [L]
```

This gets the job done, but not entirely. For example:

If I goto http://domain.com/, it displays `index.php` from inside the `domain` folder. If I goto http://domain.com/test/, it will display the contents (or 403) of the `test` folder. **BUT** if I goto http://domain.com/test (for use of shortcuts, or even to display the folder) I get redirected to http://domain.com/domain/test/.

That is not supposed to happen. If anything, it either does a mask from the .htaccess (if test is being used) or should just goto http://domain.com/test/. I have tried to figure out a way around this, and I cannot. So I am seeking your help! :)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a job for vhosts not for .htaccess

Comment: I'm using .htaccess. So please provide support as such, instead of making me learn something else.

Comment: You don't need to learn anything, you only have to change a path in your vhosts.conf and restart the server.

Comment: "So please provide support as such, instead of making me learn something else." --- SO is not a place when you can specify what and how answerers to answer. Whether you accept answer or not - don't forget it is a site where *professionals* help *professionals*, not your personal free support.

Comment: Guys, as I understand, he just not have access to server, but have .htaccess.

Comment: @Alexander: this may be, but in this case he usually should have a tool like confixx available to configure the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this: its a little crude, but should do what you want. There is a little bit of confusion: some of what I've tried to do will depend on your RewriteBase (you might need to remove one or more / characters).

I've basically added an initial block that specifically looks for directories within your */domain/* folder that don't end with a trailing slash and added one. Let me know if it works at all.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain/
RewriteCond /domain/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /domain/index.php [L]
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I still get the same effect as the original coding.

Answer (score 3):

The commenter is right, if you want to `use a sub-directory as the root folder for one of my domains` ,  just configure it in you apache virtual host configuration (*[DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot)*).

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1/ [L]
```

The above code successfully does everything I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use RewriteBase like this:

RewriteBase /f2f/f2fweb

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is auto.htaccess generator on my host!!!!

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain.com/TEST//.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|gif|png|bmp|mp4|3gp|m4a|m4r|aac|mp3|ogg|wave)$ - [F]
```