# How can the document root be changed in web server behavior?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'd like to know if there is a way of changing the relative document root for extra security. I'll try to explain myself through the following example:

```
/root
    /app
    /public
```

Say an `www.example.com` request to the web server would point to the `root` folder.
I was wondering if there was a configuration, for instance through an `.htaccess` file located in said `root` folder, that would make the server point to the `public` folder instead, therefore having any remote paths always be relative to said `public` folder.
In this instance, `www.example.com/app` would request an `app` folder inside of `public`, instead of an `app` folder inside of `root`, leaving the latter to be inaccessible from a remote url request.
In the same manner, `www.example.com/public` would request a `public` folder inside of our root `public` folder and so forth.

I've read various topics like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986473/htaccess-change-domain-root-to-sub-directory) that mention using a custom `.htaccess` configuration to achieve something similar, but it requires the manual configuration of the request url in said file, while my intention is for it to work without further configuration no matter where you host the application.
Another possible solution I've seen is doing a hard redirect through the `.htaccess` file, which does not solve anything actually.

Feel free to edit this post as I might have had a hard time trying to get my point across.

Comment: Do you have access to the whole server? Or you just have a cPanel or similar?

Comment: Cpanel, and that's the idea, to prepare it for installment on most types of hosting. Hence why I asked for a dynamic solution, if any.

Comment: Normally, in shared hostings (and you could do the same in case of a dedicated one), your site goes into a `/public_html` folder. You can place any other files outside of it, and you don't need to modify anything. Doesn't that work for you? If not, why? Sorry if I didn't get your problem yet.

Comment: The thing is, someone could want to use this on a subdomain, for instance, or organise their files on the remote server differently than by default. That's why I'm asking for a configuration inside the application files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you point your server to the public folder anyhow, as it is much more secure, you could see that all frameworks behave the same way, they all have a "public" folder where the server points to.

In the public folder you have one point of entry to your scripts, like

```
index.php
```

and from this entry you will communicate with your application.

Of course you can still work the way you requested, and it will work great, but who knows maybe you will miss something and someone could access and view your "inner" files.

Comment: From what I gathered from what I've read and all the answers I got, it's not possible to do what I was asking as the document root is apparently resolved before apache looks for an htaccess file, and that local request can't be modified through said htaccess. Setting the server to look for a public folder or just setting it manually seems the only secure option. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this simple `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any request on your server will point to the public folder.

Inside the public folder you can add an extra `.htaccess` file handling your site rules.

Comment: It's not changing the relative path, just attempting to redirect any request to the public folder.

Comment: What's the difference ? if someone calls `http://www.example.com/css/style.css` he will get the file from public folder without seeing the actual rewriting.

Comment: It actually shows the rewriting in the url, like a hard redirect. Also it's just a patch, as it is not actually changing the root of remote requests, just redirecting them, ergo not what I was asking.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre I'm getting a 500 response code with this htaccess due to constant redirect. Log says: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Comment: There's really no difference between "changing the root" and "internally redirecting them".  There's 1 document root, and you don't want to change it (because it requires access to httpd.conf). mod_rewrite is the simplest way to map URL's to new filesystem paths.

Comment: added basic anti-looping check to florian's answer

Answer (score 4):

Also you can Host multiple sites on One webserver. You can combine making VirtualHosts and Alias using mod_alias mentioned before

In this example is suposed to have your own server (either dedicated or VPS)

By using Virtualhosts you can tell to the webserver when you recieve a request to www.example.com to serve content from a specific folder.

An example Virtualhost of it is:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
ServerName ^domain_or_ip^

DocumentRoot  ^path of the public folder^

DirectoryIndex index.php home.php index.html index.htm

ErrorLog ^path for a file containing php errors^
CustomLog ^path for logging whitch browser and ip visited your site^ combined
</Virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on Apache web server? If I understand correctly, you're looking for Virtual Directories. Usually, we have to put our web application inside the document root of Apache in order to make the application accessible from the network. However, there is a trick to make the web application still accessible even though we put it outside of Apache's document root. Please read up on that here: http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-virtual-directory-apache
Credits to W3Shaman.com, obviously.